# Unique value in list of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following list of lists in python :

```
[
    u'aaaaa', 
    [1, 6, u'testing', 20.0, 18.0, 2.0, 'In time'], 
    u'zzzzzz', 
    [1, 6, u'testing', 20.0, 18.0, 2.0, 'In time'], 
    [1, 1, u'xyz ', 30.0, 25.0, 5.0, 'On Going'], 
    [2, 1, u'abcd', 10.0, 8.0, 2.0, 'In time'], 
    u'bbbbb', 
    [1, 6, u'testing', 20.0, 18.0, 2.0, 'In time'], 
    [1, 1, u'xyz ', 30.0, 25.0, 5.0, 'On Going'], 
    [2, 1, u'abcd', 10.0, 8.0, 2.0, 'In time'], 
    [1, 7, u'develop', 20.0, 15.0, 5.0, 'On Going']
]
```

I want following output in python :

```
[
    [u'aaaaa', [1, 6, u'testing', 20.0, 18.0, 2.0, 'In time']], 
    [u'zzzzzz', [1, 1, u'xyz ', 30.0, 25.0, 5.0, 'On Going'], [2, 1, u'abcd', 10.0, 8.0, 2.0, 'In time']], 
    [u'bbbbb', [1, 7, u'develop', 20.0, 15.0, 5.0, 'On Going']]
]
```

Please suggest me how can it possible with manage order in python.

Comment: If you're talking about removing duplicate values but preserving order, then this should help you: [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)

Comment: Its working but here is something change, i got after follow this link is : u'zzzzzz', [1, 1, u'xyz ', 30.0, 25.0, 5.0, 'On Going'], [2, 1, u'abcd', 10.0, 8.0, 2.0, 'In time'], but i want every eleemnt in pair like this [u'zzzzzz', [1, 1, u'xyz ', 30.0, 25.0, 5.0, 'On Going'], [2, 1, u'abcd', 10.0, 8.0, 2.0, 'In time']], 
    [u'bbbbb', [1, 7, u'develop', 20.0, 15.0, 5.0, 'On Going']]  please suggest me hows its possible :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should give you the desired output. It uses a dictionary to spot duplicate entries.

```
entries = [
    u'aaaaa', [1, 6, u'testing', 20.0, 18.0, 2.0, 'In time'],
    u'zzzzzz', [1, 6, u'testing', 20.0, 18.0, 2.0, 'In time'], 
    [1, 1, u'xyz ', 30.0, 25.0, 5.0, 'On Going'], 
    [2, 1, u'abcd', 10.0, 8.0, 2.0, 'In time'],
    u'bbbbb', 
    [1, 6, u'testing', 20.0, 18.0, 2.0, 'In time'], 
    [1, 1, u'xyz ', 30.0, 25.0, 5.0, 'On Going'], 
    [2, 1, u'abcd', 10.0, 8.0, 2.0, 'In time'], 
    [1, 7, u'develop', 20.0, 15.0, 5.0, 'On Going']]

d = {}
output = []
entry = []

for item in entries:
    if type(item) == type([]):
        t = tuple(item)
        if t not in d:
            d[t] = 0
            entry.append(item)
    else:
        if len(entry):
            output.append(entry)

        entry = [item]

output.append(entry)

print output
```

This gives the following output:

```
[[u'aaaaa', [1, 6, u'testing', 20.0, 18.0, 2.0, 'In time']], [u'zzzzzz', [1, 1, u'xyz ', 30.0, 25.0, 5.0, 'On Going'], [2, 1, u'abcd', 10.0, 8.0, 2.0, 'In time']], [u'bbbbb', [1, 7, u'develop', 20.0, 15.0, 5.0, 'On Going']]]
```

Tested using Python 2.7

**Update:** If a list of lists format is needed, simply add `[]` to `item` in the above script as follows::

```
entry.append([item])
```

This would give the following output:

```
[[u'aaaaa', [[1, 6, u'testing', 20.0, 18.0, 2.0, 'In time']]], [u'zzzzzz', [[1, 1, u'xyz ', 30.0, 25.0, 5.0, 'On Going']], [[2, 1, u'abcd', 10.0, 8.0, 2.0, 'In time']]], [u'bbbbb', [[1, 7, u'develop', 20.0, 15.0, 5.0, 'On Going']]]]
```

Comment: hello Martin, if as possible please suggest me how its possible : I want inner list of element in list of lists format like this  because in print RML report other format is not properly working so please suggest me how i do this :[[u'aaaaa', [
            [1, 6, u'testing', 20.0, 18.0, 2.0, 'In time']
        ]], 
    [u'Administrator',[ 
            [1, 1, u'xyz', 30.0, 25.0, 5.0, 'On Going'], 
            [2, 1, u'abcd', 10.0, 8.0, 2.0, 'In time']
        ]],[u'bbbbb',
        [ 
            [1, 7, u'develop', 20.0, 15.0, 5.0, 'On Going']
        ]]]

Comment: You just need to add `[]` to one of the appends. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I got your answer but sorry, I not need that output .your suggest is proper for single list of element but in that admin have 2 list of elements so i want like this : [u'Administrator',
        [
          [1, 1, u'xyz', 30.0, 25.0, 5.0, 'On Going'], 
          [2, 1, u'abcd', 10.0, 8.0, 2.0, 'In time'],
        ]
    ],   first and last is properly working after your suggestion but what about this one please suggest me how it possible.Thanks

Comment: That is exactly what the code produces, I was just displaying it item by item. If you just print `output` you will see. I have made that simple change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all unique values from a list:

```
mylist = [u'nowplaying', u'PBS', u'PBS', u'nowplaying', u'job', u'debate', u'thenandnow']
mylist = [list(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in testdata)]
print myset # This is now a set containing all unique values.
# This will not maintain the order of the items
```

Comment: That is only applicable for hashable items, here the inner elements are list, you cannot have lists inside set.

Comment: Updated to be converted to list, and be OK with list elements.

Answer (score 0):

1) I really think you should check out Python dictionaries. They would make much more sense, looking at the kind of output you want.

2) In this case, if I understand you correctly, you want to convert a list with elements that are either strings or lists into a list of lists. This list of lists should have a starting element as a string, and the remaining elements as the following list items within the main list, till you hit the next string. (At least that's what it looks like from your example).

```
output_list = []
for elem in main_list:
    if isinstance(elem,basestring):
        output_list.append([elem])
    else:
        output_list[-1].append(elem)
```

Comment: after trying this code python display error " list index out of range" I want to create pair in that first one is name and second one is one or more than one list in python

Comment: Change Line 3 to `type(u'')` since you're using only unicode

Comment: Or, `isinstance(elem,basestring)` if you'll be using both strings and unicode strings